# Different style for one data Php/SQL

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, word-cloud

I'm trying to create a word cloud with PHP, CSS and SQL. The user can enter any word and it will be integrated into the word cloud.

The problem is that the word cloud works with CSS `li` class (the words are separated by text transformation, color, size etc ...).

Below is my attempt. The problem is everything is repeated and I don't know how I can put every word from my SQL database in the different class of `<li>` (see the screenshot).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wordcloud.css">
<title>Nuage de mot</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wordcloud', 'root', 'root');

$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM form_element');
$donnees = $reponse->fetch();

?>
<ul class="word-cloud">
<?php while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
    ?>
    <li class="word-cloud__word  word-cloud__word--x-small"><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>
    <li class="word-cloud__word  word-cloud__word--small"><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>
    <li class="word-cloud__word  word-cloud__word--large"><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>
    <li class="word-cloud__word"><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>
<?php 
}
$reponse->closeCursor();
?>
</ul>
<div>
<a href="form.html"><input type="button" value="Ajouter un nouveau mot"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

---

This part is ok, when I put word in my form, they are in the cloud.

But now you were right, I have to integrate the notion of occurrences...

Words repeated xx times have to be bigger...

I have to change my database ?

I thought to create a column "repeated words" and create an `if` function in my form. But I don't know if it possible for the script to recognize, the word for example "hello", the  number of times it is present in my colum "repeated word".

Comment: you do know you can [edit] your question when you have additional info? Stack Overflow is not a threaded forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, just a idea how you can do it.

```
$counter = 0;
<?php while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{

$counter++;

if($counter == 1) { ?>
 <li class="word-cloud__word  word-cloud__word--x-small"><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>
<?php }
if($counter == 2) { ?>
 <li class="word-cloud__word  word-cloud__word--small"><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>
 <?php }
if($counter == 3) { ?>
 <li class="word-cloud__word  word-cloud__word--large"><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>
<?php }
if($counter == 4) { ?>
<li class="word-cloud__word"><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>
<?php $counter = 0;
}
 ?>
```

May there are some syntax errors with the `<?php ?>` havent checked it. But I think you should know what I mean and you'll find the error by yourself if there are some. ;)

Comment: I don't know what is the ++, I mean I don't understand how it works. I have to check that ;). Thanks !

Comment: counter++ means it increments counter everytime it passes this line. So means at the beginning counter is 0. Then your while-loop is triggered because there are more responses to fetch, so counter will be 1. For the next result, counter will be 2 etc. Means that ++ simply increments the value by +1. The same for --. Its the opposite of ++, means that the value will be decremented.

Comment: Ok yeah looks great. 
Yeah there is syntax error, I try to fix it but I'm not an expert ^^

Answer (score 0):

Suppose The Following Case :

```
row < 10 then small font
row > 10 and row < 20 then medium font
row > 20 then large font
```

**Step 1:**

Count The Total Row From The Database Which You Want to Categorized. 
For Example :

```
$response = $bdd->query('SELECT count(id) AS total_row FROM form_element');
```

Now Suppose You Get 17 Records.

So In PHP. Do It Like This ;

**Step 2 :**

```
if($donnees['total_row'] < 10 ){
    echo "<li class="word-cloud__word  word-cloud__word--x-small"><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>";    // Output Small Font
}
else if($donnees['total_row'] > 10 && $donnees['total_row'] < 10 ){
    echo " <li class="word-cloud__word  word-cloud__word--small"><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>";    // Output Medium Font
}
else if($donnees['total_row'] > 20 ){
    echo " <li class="word-cloud__word  word-cloud__word--large"><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>";    // Output Large Font
}
else{
    echo " <li class="word-cloud__word "><?php echo $donnees['mot']?></li>";    // Output Same Font
}
```

Comment: Ok ! When I var_dump $donnees, it counts the number of words in the table. But it not displays the words. Have you an idea for displaying the different `<li class>` related with the occurrence of words ?